# Confirm the ending of a string without using endsWith()

Tags: javascript

**Aim:**

Check if a string (first argument, str) ends with the given target string (second argument, target). This challenge can be solved with the .endsWith() method but I don't want to use it.

**A workable solution:**

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {   
  return str.slice(str.length - target.length) === target
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "game"));  // false
```

Above is the "SOLUTION". I got frustrated after seeing how simple it was!

*However, although my code was very complicated, I still want it to work out.*

**Below is my code:**

```
function confirmEnding(str, target){
  let newStr = str.split('').reverse()
  let newTarget = target.split('').reverse()
  function matching (newStr, newTarget){
    for (let i = 0; i < newTarget.length ; i++){
    return (newTarget[i] === newStr[i]) ? true : false
    }
  }
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "game"))
```

It print `true`, but I expect it to be `false`.

- It is very messy; I want to make the loop to continue on and stop when it hits the false.. How can I do that?
- Also, I'm not quite sure where and what "return code" should be added at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the issues with your code:

1. The nested function isn't necessary
2. The loop should only return `false` if it finds a difference
3. If the loop completes without finding a difference, then you can return `true`

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target){
  let newStr = str.split('').reverse()
  let newTarget = target.split('').reverse()
  for (let i = 0; i < newTarget.length ; i++) {
    if (newTarget[i] !== newStr[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "game"))
console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "same"))
```

A more efficient way to solve the problem is with a regex:

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return new RegExp(`${target}$`).test(str);
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "game"))
console.log(confirmEnding("Open sesame", "same"))
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use regex? if you know what the ending might look like you can use regex with indexOf to verify. this assumes you are using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. The code I use here made things more intuitive to me.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let result = str.slice(-target.length);
  if (result === target) { 
    return true} else {
      return false}
}
```